# PHP Change color of text based on $value (ctype_alpha)

Tags: php, colors, var, alphabetical

What's the easiest way to change a text's color based on a variable (ctype_alpha) in PHP?

In a table on mysql I have updates about some tasks' status (pending/processing/processed)

For example:
If $var is PENDING-> red; PROCESSING-> yellow; PROCESSED-> green.

---

I know how to do it with numbers, but can't find a solution with text

Comment: Could you please add some code to show how you would solve 'it with numbers'? How do you want to change a text's color? in a terminal window or are you speaking of html (ie css) styling?

Answer (score -1):

Just use regular `if else` to decide the color

```
$var = 'PENDING';
$color = 'black';

if ($var == 'PENDING') {
   $color = 'red';
} else if ($var == 'PROCESSING') {
   $color = 'yellow';
} else if ($var == 'PROCESSED') {
   $color = 'green';
}

echo '<p style="color:'.$color.';">Text</p>'; // Use the color in style
```

Comment: Rather than have a long list of `if...else` constructs, use a `switch...case` one. It makes things easier to read and, if multiple options have the same result (e.g, PENDING and PROCESSING should both be red), this make is easier to follow as you can just "drop through" to the next option

Comment: Or just a simple associative array which is literally a mapping.